# Filter data through multiple columns and print rows?

Tags: python, pandas

Kind of a follow up on my last question. So I got this data in .csv file that looks like:

```
 id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,ip_address,birthday
 1,Ced,Begwell,cbegwell0@google.ca,Male,134.107.135.233,17/10/1978
 2,Nataline,Cheatle,ncheatle1@msn.com,Female,189.106.181.194,26/06/1989  
 3,Laverna,Hamlen,lhamlen2@dot.gov,Female,52.165.62.174,24/04/1990
 4,Gawen,Gillfillan,ggillfillan3@hp.com,Male,83.249.190.232,31/10/1984
 5,Syd,Gilfether,sgilfether4@china.com.cn,Male,180.153.199.106,11/07/1995
```

What I want is that when the python program runs it asks the user what keywords to search for. It then takes all keywords entered ( maybe they are stored in a list???), then prints out all rows that contain all keywords no matter what column that keyword is in.

I've been playing around with csv and pandas, and have been googling for hours but just can't seem to get it to work like I want it to. I'm still kinda new to python3. Please help.

**Edit to show what I've got so far:
import csv

```
# Asks for search criteria from user
search_parts = input("Enter search criteria:\n").split(",")
# Opens csv data file
file = csv.reader(open("MOCK_DATA.csv"))
# Go over each row and print it if it contains user input.
for row in file:
    if all([x in row for x in search_parts]):
        print(row)
```

Works great if only searching by one keyword. But I want the choice of filtering by one or mutiple keywords.

Comment: We would like you to show your efforts please! You shouldn't be encouraged to come here without at least having coded something yourself.

Comment: This is the closest i got `import csv
# Asks for search criteria from user
search_parts = input("Enter search criteria:\n").split(",")
# Opens csv data file
file = csv.reader(open("MOCK_DATA.csv"))
# Go over each row and print it if it contains user input.
for row in file:
    if all([x in row for x in search_parts]):
        print(row)
`    #But this only works with one keyword, I want it to use mutiple keywords as filters

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, using try and except because if the datatype is not matched with your keyword it would raise an error

```
import pandas as pd
def fun(data,keyword):
    ans = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in data.columns:
        try:
            ans = pd.concat((data[data[i]==keyword],ans))
        except:
            pass
    ans.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
    return ans
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code for `AND` search with the keywords:

```
def AND_serach(df,list_of_keywords):
    # init a numpy array to store the index
    index_arr = np.array([]) 
    for keyword in list_of_keywords:
        # drop the nan if entire row is nan and get remaining rows' indexs
        index = df[df==keyword].dropna(how='all').index.values
        # if index_arr is empty then assign to it; otherwise update to intersect of two arrays
        index_arr = index if index_arr.size == 0 else np.intersect1d(index_arr,index)
    # get back the df by filter the index
    return df.loc[index_arr.astype(int)]
```

Try the following code for `OR`search with the keywords:

```
def OR_serach(df,list_of_keywords):
    index_arr = np.array([]) 
    for keyword in list_of_keywords:
        index = df[df==keyword].dropna(how='all').index.values
        # get all the unique index
        index_arr = np.unique(np.concatenate((index_arr,index),0))
    return df.loc[index_arr.astype(int)]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
d = {'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [10,1,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print df
   A   B
0  1  10
1  2   1
2  3   5

keywords = [1,5]
AND_serach(df,keywords) # return nothing
Out[]:
    A   B

OR_serach(df,keywords)
Out[]: 
    A   B
0   1   10
1   2   1
2   3   5
```

Comment: This works great!!! Thanks!! Not gonna lie though, I don't exactly see "how" it works lol. But I'm looking into it!

Comment: Thanks: I have added the comments above. Hope you can understand how it works :)